# Show html data in spring mvc textarea

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, textarea

I try to develop a SPRING mvc application in java. And I have the following problem. I have an html page parsed through the controller and passed in the textArea as a String. Is there any way at all to present the data in the textarea in the page, by the actual html formatting and not as plain text?

My textarea is formated by this: 
`<textarea rows="17" id="employment offer" class="fullWidth" title="" name="offer"><c:out value="${content}" /></textarea>` where content is the html string that I want to show as an actual html formated String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the right way to do this was add the following attribute: escapeXml="false" in the text area.